# Fila en datagridview no se selecciona

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente codigo para seleccionar una fila al encontrar el Id buscado, mi problema es que se activa la fila pero no se selecciona, no se sombrea en azul, hice esto en otro formulario que tengo y me funciono, si me la activa y me la sombrea y esta todo igual, que puede ser. ¿Por que el `Selected` no me funciona?

```
private void btnBuscarProv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmBuscarProv frmBProv = new frmBuscarProv();
            frmBProv.idempresaMB = idempresaM;
            frmBProv.ShowDialog();

            foreach(DataGridViewRow filaSelec in dgvProveedor.Rows)            
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(filaSelec.Cells["IdProveedor"].Value) == idproveedorB)
                {
                    filaSelec.Selected = true;                    
                    dgvProveedor.CurrentCell = dgvProveedor.Rows[filaProveedorB].Cells[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    filaSelec.Selected = false;
                }
            }        
        }
```

Comment: de donde sale el valor que toma la variable `idproveedorB` ?

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises la propiedad `MultiSelect` de tu `DataGridView`que este establecida a `dgvProveedor.MultiSelect = true;` revisa además la propiedad `RowTemplate` esta es una estructura que contiene una propiedad `DefaultCellStyle` que establece entre otras cosas los colores de las celdas seleccionadas, revisa esto también, he usado la  propiedad `xxx.Selected = true;` en un sin número de ocasiones y siempre ha funcionado.

Comment: @EduardoReyes muchas gracias, me funciono, en el diseñador estaba en true, pero me fije que el código estaba en false, no sabía que esa simple linea me iba a hacer eso jeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema en la seleccion se debe a como lo configuras en el grid

Tienes que definir la propiedad `SelectionMode` con la opcion `FullRowSelect`

[Modos de selección en el control DataGridView de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/selection-modes-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Ademas no necesitas poner en false todas las filas, puedes usar

[DataGridView.ClearSelection()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection?view=netframework-4.8)

al principio, asi limpias la seleccion previa

```
private void btnBuscarProv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmBuscarProv frmBProv = new frmBuscarProv();
    frmBProv.idempresaMB = idempresaM;
    frmBProv.ShowDialog();

    dgvProveedor.ClearSelection();

    var row = dgvProveedor.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                          .FirstOrDefault(r=> Convert.ToString(r.Cells["IdProveedor"].Value) == idproveedorB);
    if(row != null)
    {
        row.Selected = true;                    
        dgvProveedor.CurrentRow = row;
    }      
}
```

Si te animas con `linq` es mucho mas simple de obtener la row

Igual creo que redundante asignar el `Selected` y el `CurrentRow` creo que solo asignando uno alcanza

[DataGridView.CurrentRow](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, probé el código y también me funciono, no sabía que había otra manera de seleccionar una fila con Linq